Relation between individual $i.i.d.$ random variables and their sample mean
Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be $i.i.d.$ random variables, and define the sample mean $M_n=\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n}$.
Let $\omega \in \Omega$.
Since the random variables are $i.i.d.$s, and addition is pointwise, $X_1(\omega)=...=X_n(\omega)(=k\in\mathbb R$, say$)$
Now, $M_n(\omega)=\frac{(X_1+...+X_n)(\omega)}{n}=\frac{X_1(\omega)+...+X_n(\omega)}{n}=\frac{nk}{n}=k=X_1(\omega)$.
So, the random variable $M_n$ is the same as any of the $X_i$'s$($since they agree for all $\omega\in\Omega)$, which clearly isn't the case.
Where am I going wrong? I suspect that I am getting the concept of identically distributed random variables wrong among other things. If so, it would be very helpful if additionally  an example is provided. Also, if wrong, what are the cases in which the above equality holds?
$\textbf{P.S.:}$ There are certain 'graphs' available on the internet, plotting the sample mean $M_n$ against $n$. Are such plots, of random variables in general, made by fixing a particular value for $\omega$ and plotting the values of $M_n(\omega)$, a real number, against $n$?

You have  awrong idea of what i.i.d means. It is wrong to say 'Since the random variables are $i.i.d.$s, and addition is pointwise, $X_1(\omega)=...=X_n(\omega)(=k\in\mathbb R$, say$)$'. Two random variables with the same distribution need not be equal.

@geetha290krm yes, I just found such an example for this part. What about the others, and the graph thing?

Graphs can either be the results of experiments or the probability distribution of $M_n$

I would assume that you don't know measure theoratic probability so here is an intuitive way to think about it. Say there are $n$ mathematicians who are each rolling a fair die once and recording the value they observe.
Here, identical distribution, corresponds to the $n$ people having identical conditions and having identical dice.
Think of fixing an $\omega$ as the cue that all the $n$ people can now begin rolling their own die and the vector $(X_{1}(\omega),...,X_{n}(\omega))$ are the $n$ values which the mathematicians observed.
Now, just because all the dice are same, does it mean that all the mathematicians must get the same value in their roll? Well, they can in some particular run of the experiment (i.e. for some particular $\omega$), but in general, they can get any values.
But, the point is that, $P(X_{1}=k)=P(X_{2}=k)=...=P(X_{n}=k)=\frac{1}{6}$ for any $k=1,2,...6$ because the dices were all fair and identical. This is what is meant by identically distributed.
So the sample mean for one particular run of the experiment($\omega$), is just the average of the values observed in that run. So $M(\omega)=\frac{X_{1}(\omega)+...+X_{n}(\omega)}{n}$.
When one is plotting the graph of sample mean, what they are doing is that for each $n$, they are running the experiment once and reporting the average. Then again for $n+1$, they are finding $n+1$ new jobless mathematicians and giving them dices and then running the experiment once and plotting the value they get.
Ofcourse, needless to say, that the graph itself will be a "random" graph. If they were to plot it again by collecting a new set $n$ mathemticains, then, $M_{n}$ might change and hence the graph will also change.
The important questions that require answering is that what happens to the graph as $n\to\infty$?Can we expect the points to be close to $3.5$, which is the expected value of the roll for most of the iterations of the experiments ? i.e. suppose you plot a 1000 of such graphs, can we expect that for most of the graphs, the points will become close to $3.5$ as $n\to\infty$? That is answered by statements like the Law of Large Numbers.

What exactly is meant by "reporting the average"? Since $M_n$ is a random variable, it is no particular 'value'. We need to feed an experiment $\omega$ to it to get  a value. So while graphing, are we really plotting ${M_1(\omega), M_2(\omega),...}$ for a fixed $\omega$?

Say we are considering the die roll model as an example. Let $X_i$ denote the $n$th roll of the die. What will the $M_n$'s be? What are the exact numbers we'd actually be plotting for $n=1,2,...$?

@ShaDy Say this plotting is being done by a computer. What it does it for each $n$, $n=1,2,...m$ , it generates $n$ independent random numbers from the set ${1,2,...6}$ and then computes the average and then plots it. This gives you a plot of $m$ many points. If you ask the computer to give you another plot of $m$ points by the same process, the plot that you get can be different from the plot that you got before. Try this yourself by writing some line of code on matlab or python whatever you like.

Okay, I think I get the idea of how the computer does this. I have constructed this sequence of r.v.s, I hope this works.
(Representation of distribution: $($face of dice, number associated to it$)$)
${X_1,X_2,X_3,...}$, where $X_1$ is the distribution ${(1,1),(2,2),...,(6,6)}$, $X_2$ is the distribution ${(1,2),(2,5),(3,3),(4,1),(5,6),(6,2)}$, and so on. So for a particular $\omega$, we have $X_i(\omega)$ giving different values for different $i$'s, and thus, we have a meaningful $M_n(\omega)$. So for this fixed $\omega$, we plot the $M_n$(which really is $M_n(\omega)$) vs $n$ graph.

Basically every random variable is just a possible relabeling of the face-values, keeping the probabilities unchanged. They are identically distributed, since we aren't tampering with the pdf.

@ShaDy That's one way to view it. But note that the labelling need not be distinct. i.e. two of the random variables may have same values or different (two dices can land the same face or different). Another word for "labelling" is what is mathematically called a function.

@ShaDy The rigorous deifnition is that a random variable is a "measurable" function (interpret as a "nice" function) from a space $\Omega\to\Bbb{R}$. This space  $\Omega$ along with a collection of it's subsets $\mathcal{F}$ and a function (with some properties called countable additivity) $P:\mathcal{F}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $P(\Omega)=1$ is called a probability space.  But you can safely ignore this comment till you learn measure theory/measure theoratic probability theory and then visit back.
